# C++: Is it possible to distinguish an extern "C" function from an ordinary function?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to distinguish an `extern "C"` function and a non-[`extern "C"`] function in C++ at compile time?

They have very different behavior and, evidently, are allowed to have different calling conventions (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45968482/931154).

The following code snippet suggests that it is not possible to distinguish them using information available at compile time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int cpp_add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

extern "C" int c_add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

typedef decltype(cpp_add) cpp_t;
typedef decltype(c_add) c_t;

constexpr bool sameness = std::is_same<cpp_t, c_t>::value;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (sameness)
    std::cout << "same" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "different" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

prints `same` with `gcc` and `clang` on OS X.

```
% g++ --std=c++11 externcsame.cpp && ./a.out
same

% clang++ --std=c++11 externcsame.cpp && ./a.out
same
```

Comment: May be on your system they have the same calling convention?

Comment: @VladimirBerezkin I don't think it's system-dependent in that way. I'm asking about behavior that takes place when templates are expanded ... which is before system-dependent stuff would really have a chance to influence the result.

Comment: More precisely the question is whether you can ever have a pointer to a function of a calling convention other than the one that will be used when calling via the pointer, without casting to get such pointer? No. And given that in practice the calling convention is the same by default, with all extant compilers, the problem is pretty moot.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf -- I don't follow. Given that the two functions above could potentially be compiled in very different ways, it seems natural to expose that information at compile time in some way (e.g. by having a distinct type for `extern "C"` functions). If it is exposed in some way, `std::is_same` is not capable of detecting it. If `std::is_same` considers the types the same, it might mean that the types completely indistinguishable. That's what I'm wondering about.

Comment: In the language spec [dcl.link], paragraph 1, says "Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical."  Does this mean `is_same` should be false?  `is_same` is described as "[the two types] name the same type
with the same cv-qualifications".

Comment: Tests with VS2015 give the same output.  Adding in a test for function pointer assignment works also.  Changing `c_add` to be `__stdcall` reports the types as different.  So it appears that if the calling convention is the same the two types are considered the same, despite what's in [dcl.link].

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm What is [dcl.link]? Was it originally a link to a working draft or something that got replaced with `[dcl.link]`?

Comment: It's the ID of the section in the language definition spec (either section 7.5 or 10.5, depending on the version, titled "Linkage Specifications").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions with C linkage and functions with C++ linkage have different types, even if they take the same argument types and return the same type. (Hmm, sounds familiar). But most compilers don't enforce this rule, and treat them as the same type. (Hmm, sounds familiar).

So, for example, the C++ standard specifies that `std::qsort` has **two** overloads, one that takes a function with C linkage as the comparison function, and one that takes a function with C++ linkage as the comparison function. That's just plain overloading, and the compiler is supposed to choose the appropriate overload when you call `std::qsort` with either function type.

So, yes, `std::is_same` should be all you need to distinguish the two types. But, again, most compilers don't treat them as different types. If you have one of those compilers (and you almost certainly do), then they have the same type, and you can't tell them apart. Because of that, for example, the standard library for those compilers has only **one** version of `std::qsort`.

Comment: Can you cite the passage from the standard that says that they have different types?